# Applications onto android-x86

Tags: android, linux, terminal, android-x86

I have android x86 froyo as live cd when i am inserting usb drive to pc it is detecting as sdcard . i want to know how to install .apk application residing into /sdcard/

Answer (score 0):

Put your phone in mass storage mode - copy the .apk to the SDCard.  Then use a file browser app to navigate to the SDCard, find the .apk and install it from there.

Comment: i am using android x86 as live cd in my PC,i can browse sdcard from the Alt +F1 run level but due to lack of adb cant install.

Comment: @Kaushal Are you trying to install an application on a device that is connected to the system?

Comment: no, i am using Android x86 froyo into my system as a live cd and i want to install application to my system

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this now want to share,put .apk package into usb drive which will detect in androidx86 as sdcard,press ALT+F1 which will take you to console from which mv .apk to /system/apps,then issue chown 1000:1000 apps,that will enable this application for you.